# Is Chandhramukhi / Manichitrathazhu / Bhool Bhulaiyaa a partial copy of Vertigo?

Tags: reference, vertigo, manichitrathazhu, chandramukhi, bhool-bhulaiyaa

I watched [Vertigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo_%28film%29) recently and I noticed that there were some really striking similarities between Vertigo and [Chandramukhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandramuki)/ [Manichitrathazhu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manichithrathazhu) /[Bhool Bhulaiyaa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhool_Bhulaiyaa).

Is it true that the makers really copied Vertigo, or was it really original?

Comment: I recently read the novella The Anastasia syndrome by Mary Higgin Clarke and found it very similar in theme to Manichitrathazhu. This novel was published first in 1989 and the movie was released in 1993. If it is a adaptation of the novel then it is a brilliant adaptation.

Comment: OT: The answer is NO. But if you are looking for the film that inspired from Vertigo, it's 'Mannar Mathai Speaking'

Comment: Since the question asks about Vertigo and Manichithrathazhu(made in Malayalam language), it may be worth noting that the basic plot of Vertigo was copied into Malayalam as Mannar Mathai Speaking

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Manichitrathazhu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manichithrathazhu) story is influenced from a tragedy that happened in Alummoottil Tharavadu, a famous central Travancore family, in the 19th century. Here heroine suffers from personality disorder and some strange things happen, solves problem with exorcism and psychiatry.

Where as in [Vertigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo_%28film%29), a retired police detective suffering from acrophobia who is hired as a private investigator to follow the wife of an acquaintance to uncover the mystery of her peculiar behavior. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Living_and_the_Dead_%28novel%29) novel is written by Boileau-Narcejac. Hero suffers from acrophobia.

There might be few scenes borrowed from Vertigo.

Comment: May be some scenes and plot elements match but nothing else is common in between. Manichitrathazhu seems to be an original work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think Manichithrathazhu shares any similarities with Vertigo. To me, remakes often felt like the inaccurate description of Ganga's medical condition. Her anger often directed at the man who plays the lead character. Which I feel is a deliberate nonsensical approach to give more screen time to Hero.

Manichithrathazhu script is inspired by the case diaries of a Psychiatrist. The original portrays Ganga as a patient suffering from Dissociative identity disorder. Split personality / multiple personalities have its roots in childhood trauma. Sexual abuse and other trauma, including dejection to name few causes. Lonely childhood of Ganga has enough clues to establish roots of the disease. More importantly, Manichithrathazhu has filmed strong themes around the dejection from Nakulan. Which could have triggered Split personality in Ganga's adulthood?

Watch these two scenes again:

Ganga is in bed almost dozing off. She asks Nakulan to wake her up when he is ready to sleep. Nakulan without looking at her says yes and goes on to his work. Remember,  Ganga and Nakulan are newlyweds. Her desire to spending the night with him goes unanswered.

In a different scene, Ganga passionately talks about opening Manichithrathazhu. Nakulan yet again at work desk. Nakulan nods his approval, without looking away from his computer screen.

Manichithrathazhu looks like a serious attempt to portray Dissociative identity disorder.

Answer (score 1):

Happy to bump into this old thread and feel that I am not alone. I too noticed a lot of similarities between Vertigo and Chandramukhi (Manichithrathazhu). In vertigo the heroine, Mrs. Elster is supposed to be taken by the spirit of Carlotto Valdes (a Mexican lady who settled in US in previous century and was misused by her husband and finally died). Elster used to stare at the portrait of Valdes for hours daily, she used to look at the jewels of Valdes and fondle them carefully, etc..The story line of someone who suffered and died in the past influencing the lead female character of the movie is completely stolen from Vertigo. You have to see that movie to believe it. I'm both surprised and impressed that Alfred Hitchcock made this movie in 1958 and could come up with such fantastic original story line.

Answer (score 0):

ChandraMukhi and Bhool Bhulayia are official remakes of Manichitrathazhu. However, these movies are not related to Vertigo. Some things are the same but that's co-incidence.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a little more or back your statement a little more somehow?